# why ServletContext.getResourceAsStream method return null in java web application?

Tags: java

i implemented java web application which need to read set of files from folder in project. When identify the path of this folder containing the files by using    context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/docs/") method, it return null while i try to using all structure of paths. where docs is the folder containing the files.and all the absolute path that contain the project is:    C:/Users/Alahram/Documents/WepApplication8/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/docs. but i donot want to use it to enable outsource the project to server.can any one help me to identify the correct path for this files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Du4n.png)

Comment: Remove the leading slash in "/WEB-INF"

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, still return null.

Comment: Null = not found. Are you sure the docs folder is present?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen , yes this folder docs exist in the following path:C:/Users/AlAhram/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApllication8/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/docs. this is the absolute path the docs saved in it in my PC. but in the web application i used only WEB-INF/classes/docs because i want to upload the application to server.

Comment: ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/docs/hello.txt");      this is right

Comment: but you need access by browser like : http://localhost:8080/javaweb/test.jsp

Comment: Remove `/WEB-INF/classes` completely from the string. That's already on the classpath, which is where you need it for `getResourceAsStream()`. But `/WEB-INF` itself isn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try:

```
String absoluteFolder = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/docs");
File folder = new File(absoluteFolder);
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
```

Comment: @ verejava, it also return null, should i put the folder (docs) which contain files in specific location in the application? i put it in source package. it it wrong or it is causes the problem.

Comment: you need access by browser like : localhost:8080/javaweb/test.jsp

Comment: ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext(); InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/docs/hello.txt"); this is right

Comment: please see my answer picture is sucessfully

Comment: unfortunality it also return null. i edit my question and add my project chart . can you look to it please. notice, i use servlet not JSP in my project. and my servlet class exist in (rc2 folder) in source package.

Comment: not folder /WEB-INF/classes/docs ,  need file   /WEB-INF/classes/docs/t12.txt
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/docs/t12.txt");

Comment: @ verejava, but i want to read more than one file from this folder. is there any solution for this case.what i mean that i want to loop on files in the specific folder.

Comment: String absoluteFolder = new File(application.getRealPath(request.getRequestURI())).getParent()+"/WEB-INF/classes/docs";
File folder = new File(absoluteFolder);
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

Comment: or String absoluteFolder = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/docs");

Comment: application.getRealPath, what did you mean by application here.

Comment: application.getRealPath : get your java web project real folder

Comment: you can write like this : application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/docs")

Comment: @ verejava, thank you it work correctly, now if i want to upload WAR file to server, it will work correctly, is it right?

Comment: sorry for many questions. but iam begginer in web application, if i have classes in my web application not servlet and i use relative path in it. i try alot of relative path "/WEB-INF/classes/docs" and "src/java/docs" but not of them work, it work only with absolute path ("C:/Users/Alahram/.../ . as i will upload this classes with servlet in my web application.

Comment: Test  need change to your class name

Comment: when using (public key.class.getResource("/").toString()+"docs") i get path like (file:/C:/Users/....) i want to delete file:/ from the header as it result no files in the specified folder.

Comment: URL url = Test.class.getResource("/");

String absolutePath = new File(url.toURI()).getAbsolutePath()+"/docs";

Comment: @verejava `getAbsolutePath()` does nothing useful there.